¿Por qué html guarda los campos de formulario nulos?
Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Java Spring, simulando un ATM. Quiero realizar una pantalla que permita cambiar los datos del usuario tales como nombre (nom), apellido (cognom) y email.
Sin embargo, al hacer el submit del formulario, los campos se guardan como nulos. Es probable que se me escape alguna cosa, pero he realizado todas las comprovaciones, comparándolo con otros apartados similares en el proyecto y parece que está bien enlazado todo, no soy capaz de encontrar el error.
Este es el código html:
 <form th:action="@{/ATM/canviPerfil}" th:object="${editarperfil}" method="POST">
       
       <table>
            <thead style="background-color: white; ">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">  <h2>Les teves dades</h2></td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">  <h2>Editar</h2></td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <td colspan="2"> <span th:if="${client.nom}" th:text="${client.nom}"></span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" th:field="*{nom}"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Cognom</th>
                <td colspan="2"> <span th:if="${client.cognom}" th:text="${client.cognom}"></span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="cognom" name="cognom" th:field="*{cognom}"></td>

            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <td colspan="2"> <span th:if="${client.email}" th:text="${client.email}"></span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3" ><input type="text" id="email" name="email" th:field="*{email}"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>  
        <br>
        <label th:if="${missatge}" th:text="${missatge}" class="error-message"></label>

    </div>

    <table style="border-style: none;">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td> <button type="submit" class="button" id="green-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="color:#92f092;"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
            </svg> <label>Confirmar</label></button></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"> <a href="/ATM/compte" class="button" id="red-button">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="color:#ff9898;"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>
                <label>Cancel·lar</label>
            </a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

Este el DTO:
public class EditarPerfil {
private String nom;
private String cognom;
private String email;

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public String getCognom() {
    return cognom;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

}
Y este el controlador:
@GetMapping("/canviPerfil")
    public String canviPerfil(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        model.addAttribute("editarperfil", new EditarPerfil());

        String numTargActual = (String)session.getAttribute("numTargActual");
        Optional<Targeta> optional = targetaRepository.findById(numTargActual);
        Targeta targetaActual = optional.get();
        Client client = targetaActual.getCompteCorrent().getPropietari();
      
        model.addAttribute("client", client);

    return "ATMDB/canviPerfil";
    }
    @PostMapping("/canviPerfil")
    public String processarPerfil(@ModelAttribute EditarPerfil editarperfil, Model model, HttpSession session){
        try{
        model.addAttribute("editarperfil", editarperfil);
        String numTargActual = (String)session.getAttribute("numTargActual");
        Optional<Targeta> optional = targetaRepository.findById(numTargActual);
        Targeta targetaActual = optional.get();
        
        Client client = targetaActual.getCompteCorrent().getPropietari();
        
      
        model.addAttribute("client", client);
        System.out.println(editarperfil.getNom());          

            //targetaActual.getCompteCorrent().getPropietari().setNom(nom);
            targetaRepository.save(targetaActual);

        System.out.println(editarperfil.getCognom());
        
       
        
        model.addAttribute("missatge", "Canvis guardats");
        return "ATMDB/canviPerfil";
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            model.addAttribute("missatge", "Error al editar el perfil");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
     
        return "ATMDB/canviPerfil";
    }


La solución era un pequeño detalle, el cual no revisé porque no consideré importante. La clase DTO requiere de getters y setters para funcionar.
public class EditarPerfil {
private String nom;
private String cognom;
private String email;

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public String getCognom() {
    return cognom;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
public void setCognom(String cognom) {
    this.cognom = cognom;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
